# Error Code: 1690 DOUBLE value is out of range in pow((75 + 1),261)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT POW(75 + 1, 261);
```

Doing that query returns the following error:

> Error Code: 1690 DOUBLE value is out of range in pow((75 + 1),261)

Is there any way to disable that behavior or make it return `NULL` or something to indicate an error?  As is I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT POW(COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B) FROM TABLE_A;
```

Unfortunately, I can't because `POW` fails once and the whole query dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to know if you can catch an error in a query and have it instead be null when it occurs. As far as I know this can only be done within a procedure because then you can have a EXCEPTION section that can catch the error but not have it just die. From there you can perform logic like having it return a null to a variable or whatever.

My experience is pretty limited though.